# Yup when condition inside nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

so i have a problem with conditional validation using yup.
Basically i want shipping to have required properties when the checkbox is not toggled.
I am using yup's `when` feature and i can't figure out how to reference the `sameShippingAsBilling` boolean value from that `shipping` nested object.

When checkbox is false, everything is working fine, errors are shown...
But when checkbox is checked, i get this error: `"Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default' in undefined"`

The problem is that the value in `is` callback is undefined.
Is it even possible to access the outer variables in `when` from those nested objects or not. What is the alternative way to do this?

Here is the sandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-when-nested-object-j745d?file=/src/App.js)

```
const schema = Yup.object({
  sameShippingAsBilling: Yup.bool(),
  billing: Yup.object({
    line1: Yup.string().required(),
    city: Yup.string().required(),
    country: Yup.string().required()
  }),
  shipping: Yup.object({
    line1: Yup.string().when("sameShippingAsBilling", {
      is: !val || val === false,
      then: Yup.string().required(),
    }),
    city: Yup.string().when("sameShippingAsBilling", {
      is: !val || val === false,
      then: Yup.string().required(),
    }),
    country: Yup.string().when("sameShippingAsBilling", {
      is: !val || val === false,
      then: Yup.string().required(),
    })
  })
});

const addrValues = { line1: "", city: "", country: "" };

const formOpts = {
  mode: "onChange",
  reValidateMode: "onChange",
  defaultValues: {
    sameShippingAsBilling: true,
    billing: { ...addrValues },
    shipping: { ...addrValues }
  },
  resolver: yupResolver(schema)
};

export default function CheckoutForm() {
  const methods = useForm(formOpts);
  const { watch } = methods;

  const shippingAsBilling = watch("sameShippingAsBilling");

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme()}>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
          <pre>errors: {JSON.stringify(methods.errors, null, 2)}</pre>

          <div className="group">
            <FormTextField name="billing.line1" />
            <FormTextField name="billing.city" />
            <FormTextField name="billing.country" />
          </div>

          <div>
            <FormCheckbox name="sameShippingAsBilling" />
          </div>

          {!shippingAsBilling && (
            <div className="group">
              <FormTextField name="shipping.line1" />
              <FormTextField name="shipping.city" />
              <FormTextField name="shipping.country" />
            </div>
          )}

          <div>
            <button type="submit">Pay</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can conditionally render the shape of your `shipping` object dependent on the `sameShippingAsBilling` value.

Something along these lines:

```
    // define the boolean that stores if shipping details are the same as billing
    sameShippingAsBilling: Yup.bool(),
    shipping: Yup.object().when("sameShippingAsBilling", {
        // check if the boolean is false,   
        is: (sameShippingAsBilling) => sameShippingAsBilling === false,
        // if it is false, then use an object with required properties
        then: Yup.object().shape({
          line1: Yup.string().required(),
          city: Yup.string().required(),
          country: Yup.string().required(),
        }),
        // otherwise use an object without required properties
        otherwise: Yup.object().shape({
          line1: Yup.string(),
          city: Yup.string(),
          country: Yup.string(),
        }),
      }),
```

Comment: Nice solution. Works for deeper levels of nesting too.

Comment: what if you have multiple conditions on the nested object? you will keep defining the duplicate schema's?

Comment: If there are many conditions that influence the shape of a form, I would break up the form into separate forms with dedicated validation for each form. Then I would add a state control manager that collects the content of each form and displays the correct next form based on the conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Hm, i added `.nullable().default(null)` to shipping and apparently it works.
technically still don't have access to boolean true/false,  it works because val is undefined and it adds that required condition...
For a temp solution it is fine, and i don't have to fiddle with .test() or other strange solutions.
And i don't even care at this point when a library that calls it self "dead simple object schema validation", and yet i waste time on these simple things.

Comment: "dead simple object schema validation" I wasted my many days on this as well.

Comment: this worked for me, although I used `.notRequired().default(undefined)` in my case